# Receiving "Unknown Uri" message when using managedQuery with registered ContentProvider

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm working on Sony GTV and the Logitech revue GTV.

I want to run managedQuery for the Google `quicksearchbox`.
I found after running `dumpstate`, in the "Registered ContentProviders" section,
that the Content_Uri is : "com.android.quicksearchbox.google".

But when I use that URI in a query:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.quicksearchbox.google");   
Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

I receive an "Unknown URI" error message.

It works with a YouTube content_uri:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.youtube.googletv.SuggestionProvider");  
Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what is the end goal in querying the Google quicksearchbox provider?

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply. i wish to do some kind of parental control and to catch content which is set to be blocked from the user (e.g. xxx,violence etc...) in the quicksearchbox. unfortunately , this information doesn't appear in the logcat. is there another way i can get this information. thanks. yuval.

Comment: It is not supported. Please file a feature request here: http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/                         There is some parental control support in GoogleTV: http://support.google.com/googletv/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1042522

Comment: i've added a feature request. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Querying the quicksearchbox provider is not supported.